# Printing null if a character is null

Tags: c, pointers

I have a function written in C that returns either a pointer to a value or null;

```
 char* function (char const *source char const *chars)
 {

  int size();
  int sizeSource = size(source);
  int charSource = size(chars);

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeSource; i++) 
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < charSource; j++) 
      {
          if (*(source + i) == *(chars + j)) 
          {
            return *(source + i);
          }
      }
    }
   return "NULL";

 }
```

The function works just fine and I am calling it in this manner:

```
printf("%c\n", function("ABCDEFG", "HJI"));
printf("%c\n", function("ABCDEFG", "ABC"));
```

So just to explain here, the first print statement is returning null since HJI is not in ABC and the second returns a pointer to A which is fine. My question is when I currently run it the first print statement just prints nothing, is there some sort of way I can make it print "NULL" if it comes back NULL? I'd rather not have to check each return value for NULL before I print it.

edit: I would like to keep it consistent between success and failure cases. If I change %c to %s in success cases that return a pointer I get a segmentation fault. I also would like to return something not print output in the function.

Comment: `%c` but pass in a pointer?

Comment: `char* function (char const *a, char const *b)` / `if (somethings are true)` / `*(pointer to something)` Please post real code in the future.

Comment: Your `function()` should really return `const char*`, not just `char*`

Comment: You shouldn't use `%c` with a `char *`; it expects a `char`, not a pointer.  Your function had better be returning `return *(pointer to pointer to something);` as otherwise you're returning a plain value (or whatever something is).  At the moment, your function specification is confusing, which may be why you're confused about it all.

Comment: I do want %c though since a success case in my programs prints the first character in the b string that matches a character in the a string and prints that single character, but the function returns a pointer to that character so I can produce output like "At address blank a matching character 'x' was found"

Comment: Then you are trying to achieve the unachievable.

Comment: I wonder how many warnings does this code produce (;

Comment: "I have a function written in C that returns **either**..."
This is the problem.  A function should only return one type.

Comment: So a function cannot return null?

Comment: Updated, i had pseudocode posted before

Comment: `"NULL"` implies the null pointer `NULL` which a `char` is not.  Using `"NULL"` to represent the C null character or `'\0'` is confusing.  If anything, print `"NUL"` which is the ASCII character with the same value as `'\0'`.

Answer (score 1):

change %c to %s and return the text string "NULL".

Comment: I would like to keep it consistent between success and failure cases. If I change %c to %s in success cases that return a pointer I get a segmentation fault

Comment: @user3037172: You have to design the function to be consistent, then.  At the moment, you seem to want it to return a pointer sometimes and a `char` (despite the signature saying `char *function(...)` the rest of the time.

Comment: So a char * return type cannot also return null? It should NEVER return just a char. It either returns a pointer that will go to a char or NULL, I am editing it with my full code now.

Comment: Am I misunderstanding pointers completely? If I return a char * (pointer to a char) then shouldn't I be able to dereference it to get the char value I am pointing at as well as see the address it is stored at?

Comment: if you want to deref it then you would do printf("%c\n", *function("ABCDEFG", "HJI"));

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
static void print_char_or_null(const char *s)
{
    if (s) {  /* you can use "if (s != NULL)" if you prefer */
        putc(*s, stdout);
    } else {
        printf("NULL");
    }
}
```

And change `function` to return `NULL` (not `"NULL"`) in case of failure.

Then you can do:

```
print_char_or_null(function("ABCDEFG", "HJI"));
print_char_or_null(function("ABCDEFG", "ABC"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Something ugly:

```
#define PRINT_CHAR_OR_NULL(pc) \
  printf((pc) ?"%c" :"%s", (pc) ?*(pc) :"NULL")

...

char * p = <assign as per OP's requirements>
PRINT_CHAR_OR_NULL(p);
```

To use this instead of `"NULL"` return `NULL`.